# convert pandas.tseries.offsets.Day datatype to integer datatype for simple calculations

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I took difference of two columns, each of type `pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period`. The result is of `pandas.tseries.offsets.Day` datatype. Now, I want to use the integer value of calculated time difference to do other calculations. How to do that?

[I want last column values to be simply integers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH1wD.png)

Here is what i have tried.

```
## Check if all dates are in same format and take time upto days only, which will be suitable for given data
data_dates['ExaminDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data_dates["ExaminDate"],errors='coerce', infer_datetime_format= True)
data_dates["DeathDate"] = pd.to_datetime(data_dates["DeathDate"],errors='coerce',infer_datetime_format= True)
data_dates['ExaminMY']= data_dates['ExaminDate'].dt.to_period('D')
data_dates['DeathMY']= data_dates['DeathDate'].dt.to_period('D')

## Make a new column representing time of observation for each patient, which will be difference of two columns (ExaminDate and DeathDate)

data_dates['Time(days)'] = data_dates['DeathMY'] - data_dates['ExaminMY']
```

Comment: Could you please share sample data in a way that would make it easy to reproduce?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's unclear why you choose to convert your dates to time periods in the first place - it prevents you from achieving the goal of calculating the time difference (in days) between two dates. The following two lines should, therefore, be removed:

```
data_dates['ExaminMY']= data_dates['ExaminDate'].dt.to_period('D')
data_dates['DeathMY']= data_dates['DeathDate'].dt.to_period('D')
```

Explanation: with `Period` objects and there's no clear definition of what's the time difference (in days or otherwise) between two time periods (e.g. Q42019 and Q12020). You could be referring to the starting date, the end-date, or some combination of the above. Plus, periods (offsets, really) like '1 month' or '1 quarter` can differ in the number of days they contain.

If what's you're interested in is the time difference, in days, between `DeathDate` and `ExaminDate`, just do the calculation on the original DateTime fields:

```
# I don't think you need these three lines, as you're reading the date from a file. It's just 
# to make sure the example works. 
df = pd.DataFrame({"ExamineDate": ['2020-01-15'], "DeathDate": ["2020-04-20"]})
df.ExamineDate = pd.to_datetime(df.ExamineDate)
df.DeathDate = pd.to_datetime(df.DeathDate)

# This is where the real stuff begins 
df["days_diff"] = df.DeathDate - df.ExamineDate
df["days_diff_int"] = df.days_diff.dt.days
print (df)
```

The result is:

```
  ExamineDate  DeathDate days_diff  days_diff_int
0  2020-01-15 2020-04-20   96 days             96
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not working in my code. giving the error message as "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values". The code I changed is as follows: data_dates['Time(days)'] = (data_dates['DeathMY'] - data_dates['ExaminMY'])
data_dates['Time(days)'] = data_dates['Time(days)'].dt.days()

Comment: But I figured out what's difference in ur data and my data. ur df.a datatype is pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp and mine is pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period.

Comment: @MohammadMufassirKhan As mentioned in my first comment above - could you please update the question and create a reproducible example? see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: actually data is very private and somehow i have solved my problem. So thanks for ur help